# Send javascript variable to wordpress post on save moment

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I developed a plugin that make a html list dinamycally, based on javascript change events of a select element. I need to save that post with this new list items. I think that´s necessary send this list items via ajax maybe with (wp_localize_script). How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create hidden input tag in dynamically using javascript and pass this hidden element to using post method using ajax to use in php post saving.